# Apply a script to subdirectories

Tags: bash

I have read many times that if I want to execute something over all subdirectories I should run something like one of these:

`find . -name '*' -exec command arguments {} \;`

`find . -type f -print0 | xargs -0 command arguments`

`find . -type f | xargs -I {} command arguments {} arguments`

The problem is that it works well with corefunctions, but not as expected when the command is a user-defined function or a script. How to fix it?

So what I am looking for is a line of code or a script in which I can replace `command` for `myfunction` or `myscript.sh` and it goes to every single subdirectory from current directory and executes such function or script there, with whatever arguments I supply.

Explaining in another way, I want something to work over all subdirectories as nicely as `for file in *; do command_myfunction_or_script.sh arguments $file; done` works over current directory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The examples that you give, such as:

```
find . -name '*' -exec command arguments {} \;
```

Don't go to every single subdirectory from current directory and execute `command` there, but rather execute `command` from the current directory with the path to each file listed by the find as an argument.

If what you want is to actually change directory and execute a script, you could try something like this:

```
STDIR=$PWD; IFS=$'\n'; for dir in $(find . -type d); do cd $dir; /path/to/command; cd $STDIR; done; unset IFS
```

Here the current directory is saved to `STDIR` and the bash Internal Field Separator is set to a newline so names won't split on spaces. Then for each directory (`-type d`) that `find` returns, we `cd` to that directory, execute the command (using the full path here as changing directories will break a relative path) and then cd back to the starting directory.

Comment: That is great. I adapted to this: `STDIR=$PWD; for dir in $(find . -type d 2>&-); do cd "$dir"; for file in $(find * -prune -type f 2>&-); do command "$file"; done; cd "$STDIR"; done` but there is a problem when the files or directories have spaces in the name. How can I fix that?

Comment: You could fix this by changing the bash Internal Field Separator to a newline so names won't split on spaces. I have updated my answer to show this. Hope it helps!

Comment: …but what if you have newlines in your file names?

Comment: @JohnLawrence Tried that change of yours and it worked ! Adapted: `STDIR=$PWD; IFS=$'\n'; for dir in $(find . -type d 2>&-); do cd "$dir"; for file in $(find * -prune -type f 2>&-); do command "$file"; done; cd "$STDIR"; done; unset IFS`. What a great hack this IFS, where is the documentation for that?

Comment: @kojiro Probably this should be quite rare but still an exception to think about.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of `-exec`, try `-execdir`.

It may be that in some cases you need to use `bash`:

```
foo () { echo $1; }
export -f foo
find . -type f -name '*.txt' -exec bash -c 'foo arg arg' \;
```

The last line could be:

```
find . -type f -name '*.txt' -exec bash -c 'foo "$@"' _ arg arg \;
```

Depending on what args might need expanding and when. The underscore represents `$0`.

You could use `-execdir` where I have `-exec` if that's needed.

Answer (score 1):

There may be some way to use find with a function, but it won't be terribly elegant. If you have bash 4, what you probably want to do is use globstar:

```
shopt -s globstar
for file in **/*; do
    myfunction "$file"
done
```

If you're looking for compatibility with POSIX or older versions of bash, you will be forced to source the file defining your function when you invoke bash. So something like this:

```
find <args> -exec bash -c '. funcfile;
    for file; do
        myfunction "$file"
    done' _ {} +
```

But that's just ugly. When I get to this point, I usually just put my function in a script on my `PATH` and live with it.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use a bash function, this is one way.

```
work ()
{
  local file="$1"
  local dir=$(dirname $file)
  pushd "$dir"
    echo "in directory $(pwd) working with file $(basename $file)"
  popd
}
find . -name '*' | while read line;
do
   work "$line"
done
```