# How to prevent `for` loops from parsing spaces?

Tags: bash, recursion

I have this command to go to every directory and once there run some command over every file:

```
STDIR=$PWD;
for dir in $(find . -type d 2>&-); do 
    cd "$dir";
    for file in $(find * -prune -type f 2>&-); do 
        command "$file";
    done; 
    cd "$STDIR"; 
done
```

But there is a problem when the files or directories have spaces in the name. How can I fix that?

This doubt appear when trying to apply an answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10983278/apply-a-script-to-subdirectories).

**Edit:**
A good solution also appear in [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10983727/882056). To solve the spaces problem, add

```
IFS=$'\n'
```

after the first line of the code above, and

```
unset IFS
```

after `done`.

Comment: Generally, you should never do `for i in $(command)` for word-splitting reasons.

Comment: Example here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/10984996/1276280

Comment: possible duplicate of [File names with spaces in BASH](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3967707/file-names-with-spaces-in-bash)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are three ways:

```
1) find -exec (see the answer from Sorpigal)
2) find ... | xargs
3) find ... | while read line ; do command "$line" ; done
```

The third solution has an advantage: you need not so many forks as in the variants (1) and (2). And when you need to process quite many lines it can become important.

Comment: `-execdir` is not like these examples because it executes the command from the directory the file is in, whereas your way would require an extra `cd` to be manually added.

Answer (score 4):

The short answer is, as always, "Quote the expansion," but for your case the correct answer is

```
find . -type f -execdir command {} \;
```

Answer (score 2):

I'd recommend using `find` with `-exec` and avoid using `for`.

Or use `find` with `-print0` and a program that interpret NULL characters as "new lines" like `xargs` with `--null`