# Need to remove files with spaces in Debian

Tags: find, debian, filenames, spaces

I need to find and remove files with spaces in them in a certain folder.

Comment: Your going to have to be more specific.  File *names* with spaces?  Or *files* with spaces themselves?

Comment: My answer below assumes the former, obviously.

Answer (score 1):

```
$ ls -l
total 16
-rw-r--r--  1 smw  staff  10 Feb  6 16:10 Foo Bar
-rw-r--r--  1 smw  staff  11 Feb  6 16:10 foobar


$ ls -l *\ *
-rw-r--r--  1 smw  staff  10 Feb  6 16:10 Foo Bar

$ rm -i *\ *
remove Foo Bar? y

$ ls -l
total 16
-rw-r--r--  1 smw  staff  11 Feb  6 16:10 foobar
```

Comment: That's fine if you only have the one space in all the files

Comment: It will happily delete files that have more than one space?  Try it.

Comment: You are right, sorry. Of course, that's going to erase anything with at least one space and leave the rest intact, I missed that. Anyway, I somehow read OP's request as wanting to rename the files somehow to a space-less name.

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to deal with bash's niceties when dealing with spaces...

First, you need to iterate over the files, in a way that gives you the files properly regardless of spaces. Check out [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11054129/how-to-prevent-for-loops-from-parsing-spaces). I'd favor this:

```
find ... | while read line ; do command "$line" ; done
```

And then it's a matter of using something like `sed` to change `$line` into whatever you need (such as the same thing without spaces) right where `command "$line"` is.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I removed a file with a space

```
pi@raspberrypi ~/Music $ ls -l
-rw-r--r-- 1 pi pi      0 Feb 25 16:05 Sleep Away.mp3

pi@raspberrypi ~/Music $ rm Sleep\ Away.mp3
```

use the "\" forward slash to escape any spaces